# Redirect DNS to different port with traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, traefik, self-hosting

I'm trying to make a monitoring stack with traefik, grafana, zabbix, gotify etc.
I've a domain name called **domain.tld**.

In my docker-compose, I've some services with different port (grafana for example), but I've also some services on the same port (gotify, zabbix).

I want to redirect my domain.tld with zabbix.domain.tld, grafana.domain.tld to each container with SSL.
It's works, but not exactly.

If I put in my address bar: 
**grafana.domain.tld** -> 404 Error with SSL redirection

If I put in my address bar: 
**grafana.domain.tld:3000** -> It's ok

I think, I'm little lost (or completely ?) in my many modifications..
Just doc and me is not enought.

So, my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
    traefik_front:
        external: true

services:
       traefik:
        image: traefik
        command: --api --docker
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
         - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
         - "${TRAEFIK_PATH}/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
         - "${TRAEFIK_PATH}/acme.json:/acme.json"
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

        labels:
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAIN}"
         - "treafik.port=8080"
         - "traefik.enable=true"
         - "traefik.backend=traefik"
         - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
         #- "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
        networks:
         - traefik_front


       gotify:
        image: gotify/server
        container_name: gotify
        volumes:
         - "${GOTIFY_PATH}:/app/data"
        env_file:
         - env/.env_gotify
        labels: 
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:push.${DOMAIN}"
         - "traefik.port=80"
         - "traefik.enable=true"
         - "traefik.backend=gotify"
         - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
        networks:
         - traefik_front
         - default

       grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana
        container_name: grafana
        volumes:
          - "${GF_PATH}:/var/lib/grafana"
        env_file:
         - env/.env_grafana
        labels: 
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:grafana.${DOMAIN}"
         - "traefik.port=3000"
         - "traefik.enable=true"
         - "traefik.backend=grafana"
         - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
        networks:
         - traefik_front
         - default

       zabbix-server:
        image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:ubuntu-4.0-latest
        volumes:
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/alertscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts:ro"
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/externalscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:ro"
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/modules:/var/lib/zabbix/modules:ro"
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/enc:/var/lib/zabbix/enc:ro"
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/ssh_keys:/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys:ro"
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/mibs:/var/lib/zabbix/mibs:ro"
         - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/snmptraps:/var/lib/zabbix/snmptraps:ro"
        links:
         - mysql-server:mysql-server
        env_file:
         - env/.env_zabbix_db_mysql
         - env/.env_zabbix_srv
        user: root
        depends_on:
         - mysql-server
         - zabbix-snmptraps
        labels: 
         - "traefik.backend=zabbix-server"
         - "traefik.port=10051"

       zabbix-web-apache-mysql:
        image: zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql:ubuntu-4.0-latest
        links:
          - mysql-server:mysql-server
          - zabbix-server:zabbix-server
        volumes:
          - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/ssl/apache2:/etc/ssl/apache2:ro"
        env_file:
          - env/.env_zabbix_db_mysql
          - env/.env_zabbix_web
        user: root
        depends_on:
          - mysql-server
          - zabbix-server
        labels: 
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:zabbix.${DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.port=80"
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.backend=zabbix-web"
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
        networks:
         - traefik_front
         - default

       zabbix-agent:
        image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:ubuntu-4.0-latest
        ports:
          - "10050:10050"
        volumes:
          - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/zabbix_agentd.d:/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d:ro"
          - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/modules:/var/lib/zabbix/modules:ro"
          - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/enc:/var/lib/zabbix/enc:ro"
          - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/ssh_keys:/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys:ro"
        links:
          - zabbix-server:zabbix-server
        env_file:
          - env/.env_zabbix_agent
        user: root
        networks:
         - default

       zabbix-snmptraps:
        image: zabbix/zabbix-snmptraps:ubuntu-4.0-latest
        ports:
          - "162:162/udp"
        volumes:
          - "${ZABBIX_PATH}/snmptraps:/var/lib/zabbix/snmptraps:rw"
        user: root
        networks:
         - default

       mysql-server:
        image: mysql:5.7
        command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8, --collation-server=utf8_bin]
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
        env_file:
          - env/.env_zabbix_db_mysql
        labels: 
          - "traefik.enable=false"
        user: root
        networks:
         - default
```

And my traefik.toml:

```
# WEBUI
[web]
entryPoint = "dashboard"
dashboard = true
address = ":8080"
usersFile = "/etc/docker/traefik/.htpasswd"

logLevel = "ERROR"

# Force HTTPS
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":8080"
[entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
        [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]


[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
domain = "domain.tld"
network = "traefik_front"

# Let's Encrypt
[acme]
    email = "mail@mail.fr"
    storage = "acme.json"
    entryPoint = "https"
    onHostRule = true
    onDemand = false
[acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
OnHostRule = true
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.tld"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.tld"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.tld"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.tld"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, and it would look this on your setup

docker-compose.yml

```
service:
  traefik:
    labels:
         - "treafik.port=8080"
         - "traefik.enable=true"
         - "traefik.backend=traefik"
         - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAIN}"
         - "traefik.webservice.frontend.entryPoints=https"

  zabbix-web-apache-mysql:
    labels: 
          - "traefik.port=80"
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.backend=zabbix-web"
          - "traefik.passHostHeader=true"
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:zabbix.${DOMAIN}"

  grafana:
        labels: 
         - "traefik.port=3000"
         - "traefik.enable=true"
         - "traefik.backend=grafana"
         - "traefik.passHostHeader=true"
         - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_front"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:grafana.${DOMAIN}"
```

and the way my traefik.toml is configured

```
InsecureSkipVerify = true ## This is optional 

## Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    passHostHeader = true
    address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.forwardedHeaders]
        insecure = true
      [entryPoints.http.proxyProtocol]
        insecure = true
       ## This seems to be an absolute requirement for redirect 
       ## ...but it redirects every request to https
      [entryPoints.http.redirect] 
        entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8080"
      [entryPoints.traefik.auth.basic]
        # the "user" password is the MD5 encrpytion of the word "pass"
        users = ["user:$apr1$.LWU4fEi$4YipxeuXs5T0xulH3S7Kb."] 
  [entryPoints.https]
    passHostHeader = true
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls] ## This seems to be an absolute requirement
      [entryPoints.https.forwardedHeaders]
        insecure = true
      [entryPoints.https.proxyProtocol]
        insecure = true
```